Difficulty putting the end result of each run of a simulation into a matrix in numpy. Only adding last simulation
I have a simulation modeling a viral spread for a school project. Finally the simulation itself works as it is supposed to (as ugly and hacked as it is as I am new to python).
I loop through the simulation 'n' number of times so that I can converge on a statistically significant end result. I have been trying to write a code to export the final answer (number of days that the pandemic lasts) for each simulation into a matrix so that I can export it and play with it on excel and such and do some visualization. After each simulation there is a value 'days' that I am trying to save in a matrix as this is my end result.
However, I can only get it to save the result of the final run of the simulation and can't get it to add the result from each simulation before it. The desired result is a matrix that is as long as the number of simulations run (n) and has the final value of 'days' for each of those elements.
I think the issue with the outermost loop, everything in the core works as it should.
Any help is appreciated!
import numpy #go numpy, you can do it!#

# How many times to run the simulation #
n = s = 3
pandemiclength1 = []
pandemiclength2 = []

while n > 0:

        #variable defintions 
        day = 0
        p =0.01
        infected = 0
        daysinfected = numpy.zeros(60)
        z = 0
        n = n -1


        # Day one of the simulation
        print(' ')
        print('==========================')
        print("DAY: 0")
        print('==========================')
        result = numpy.random.binomial(1, p, 60) 
        print (result)
        for ele in result: 
                if (ele == 1):
                    infected = infected +1
        print ("Number Infected:", infected)

        #for ele in result:

        daysinfected = numpy.where(result == 1, +3, 0) # sets new array to track number of addittional (excl. day 0) days infectious

        print("Days Infected")
        print(daysinfected)


        # ********** Day n of simulation ********** #

        # This portion of the code will iterate the daily trials until the number of infected children = 0

        while infected > 0: # temporary <10 just to test and limit infinite run while making decay term
           day = day +1
           print(' ')
           print('==========================')
           print("DAY:", day)
           print('==========================')

        # This portion of code iterates within a single given subsequent day.
        # It takes the number of initially infected children on day 1
        # and if the element (child) is '1' (i.e., already infected)
        # it does nothing and the element remains '1' and if the element (child) is '0' subjects it
        # to a number of possibly infectious interactions equal to the number of infected children.
        # The net result is that the number of infected elements (children) increases as each '0'
        # is subjected to a number of trials equal to the number of infected children possibly converting
        # a 0 to a 1. This total will then feed into the next subsequent day as the new number of infected.

           daysinfected = numpy.where(daysinfected > 0, [x - 1 for x in daysinfected], 0) # for each day, adjust the days infectious for each element



           for i in range (len(daysinfected)):              #trying to set -1 as imunity
                 if result[i] == 1 and daysinfected[i] == 0:
                     result[i]= -1                         #asign -1 to value if conditions met

           infected = infected - z  #you don't want to do this every time...just once...oterhwise you will be constantly be subtracting more and more -1s...broke down betwen day 3 and 4
           print("Children Infected at Start of Day:", infected)
           #print("debug")
           #print(infected)


           for i in range(infected):                            # iterate for the number of initially infected kids                       
                  print("---trial", i, "---")
                  new_values = numpy.random.binomial(1, p, 60)     # not 100% why this works or why it is needed for next step - stack exchange help.
                  result = numpy.where(result == 0, new_values, result*1) # if original result is 1 leave as 1, if 0 replace with new value (could be 0 or 1)
                  infected = 0                                     # reset infected counter to 0
                  for ele in result:                               # count the number of infected children after each trial
                      if (ele == 1):
                          infected = infected +1

                  for i in range (len(daysinfected)):              # set infectious days to two subsequent days if new positve (1) result
                     if result[i] == 1 and daysinfected[i] == 0:   # only set for NEW results not if existing infectious
                         daysinfected[i]= 3                         


                  print(result)                                    # print the resulting matrix after each trial
                  print("Number Infected:", infected)              # print the number of infected children after each trial
                  print("Days Infected")
                  print(daysinfected)

           z = numpy.count_nonzero(daysinfected == 1)              # count number about to be immunized to subtract from start of next day 
           print("Totalabouttoflip", z)


           print("Total Infected at End of", day, "days is", infected)
           print("Days Infected - less 1")
           print(daysinfected)

           pandemiclength2 = numpy.append(pandemiclength1, day)
pandemiclength1 = pandemiclength2
print("The Results of", s+1, "simulations is", pandemiclength2)

       


Is your question about this line: pandemiclength2 = numpy.append(pandemiclength1, day)? You probably meant to create just a single pandemic_length list at the start and then do pandemic_length.append(days) at the end of each while loop (which should probably be a for loop). np.append is often used incorrectly.

@jared
Thank you so much for this answer. I spent like 2 hours trying to figure that out and what you suggested works perfectly. Was it just that I was putting the wrong stuff into the np.append() function? Come to think of it, I don't even know where I got that syntax from? Maybe from traditional python vs. numpy? So for numpy, it looks like the right way is to "array.append(what you append by)" vs. what I did.

np.append(a, b) creates a copy of numpy array a and extends onto it the values in numpy array b. Here, your numpy array a was pandemiclength1 (which is empty and never modified) and b is day. So every loop you extended the empty list with day (giving you just np.array([day])) and saved it to the variable pandemiclength2, overwriting that value every loop. So, all you saw at the end was the final result. If you wanted to use np.append you would have to use a single numpy array defined at the start and then did pandemiclength2 = np.append(pandemiclength2, day).
